# a Prolog function that returns a list without a member

Tags: prolog

Ello, ive got the Prolog function member which tells us if an element exists in a list.

now i should create a function that returns a list without that element. i know more or less how it should look like, but somehow i have no idea how to do it.

ideas so far:

- return the elements in the list before our element, and concat it with the rest of the list after our element.
- use member() in a predicate that goes through the list recursively and builds it.

help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Seems like homework to me so I'll give you an outline containing some hints ;-)

Given `[H|T]`...

- ... if `H` is the element to remove, return `T`, (If you need to remove *all* such elements, remember to recurse on `T` as well.)
- ... if `H` is *not* the element to remove, return `[H|NewTail]` where `NewTail` is result of recursively removing the element from `T`.